# Catalina issues with FD_SETSIZE and MySQL, Configuration not read

Tags: mysql, macos-catalina, ulimit

I',m having a huge issue with running MySQL@5.7 on my freshly installed 16" Macbook (with OSX 10.15.1 Catalina) During certain actions I get errors like 
`PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away.`

This is caused by the following error I found in the MySQL log.

```
2019-11-27T13:24:04.835245Z 0 [Warning] File Descriptor 3226 exceeded FD_SETSIZE=1024
```

After some research, I tried stuff like `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000`

When i run `launchctl limit` i get the follwing data

```
    cpu         unlimited      unlimited
    filesize    unlimited      unlimited
    data        unlimited      unlimited
    stack       8388608        67104768
    core        0              unlimited
    rss         unlimited      unlimited
    memlock     unlimited      unlimited
    maxproc     4096           4096
    maxfiles    524288         524288
```

This looks fine to me. To get the max processes and max files correct I also tried

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
```

my.cnf looks like this

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit=999999
local_infile=ON
secure_file_priv=""
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
max_connections=100000
key_buffer_size=2G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
query_cache_size=67108864
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=4194304
table_open_cache=4096
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=24
innodb_sort_buffer_size=2G
sort_buffer_size=1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_log_file_size=3G
interactive_timeout=3600
max_connect_errors=1000000
thread_cache_size=4096
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit=999999
```

There is of course a solution to change my `table_open_cache` to a lower value but that hurts performance and before i always had this on a higher number.

Anybody any clue where this FD_SETSIZE is coming from and how to change it so its used properly
rebooting has no effect by the way.

Comment: Does this help? [expressionengine](https://expressionengine.com/blog/mysql-5.7-server-os-x-has-gone-away)

Comment: I now changed my db to innodb_file_per_table=OFF that seems to help some what.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post to pastebin.com your complete error log content?

Answer (score 1):

Resource explaining issue: https://expressionengine.com/blog/mysql-5.7-server-os-x-has-gone-away

try setting following environment variables in mysql configuration file (my.cnf)

```
interactive_timeout = 300
wait_timeout = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on Big Sur v 11.6. The solution for me was modifying the MySQL config with:

```
max_allowed_packet=256M
table_open_cache=250
```